# После обновления перестала запускаться MySQL

Tags: mysql, freebsd

Друзья, после обновления mysql, она напрочь перестала запускаться, поиски не дали результатов, вот лог:

```
2018-03-30T07:34:59.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/db/mysql/webserver.err'.
2018-03-30T07:34:59.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
2018-03-30T07:35:00.875147Z 0 [Note] Basedir set to /usr/local/
2018-03-30T07:35:00.885478Z 0 [Warning] The syntax '--symbolic-links/-s' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2018-03-30T07:35:00.885590Z 0 [Warning] The syntax '--symbolic-links/-s' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2018-03-30T07:35:00.930196Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.2-dmr-log) starting as process 1882 ...
2018-03-30T07:35:01.196338Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-03-30T07:35:01.309459Z 1 [ERROR] Failed to find valid data directory.
2018-03-30T07:35:01.309726Z 0 [ERROR] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2018-03-30T07:35:01.309744Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2018-03-30T07:35:01.309768Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-03-30T07:35:01.309830Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2018-03-30T07:35:01.310203Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2018-03-30T07:35:01.310224Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-03-30T07:35:01.314400Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2018-03-30T07:35:01.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/webserver.pid ended
```

Вот мой конфиг **my.cnf**:

```
# $FreeBSD: branches/2018Q1/databases/mysql80-server/files/my.cnf.sample.in 414707 2016-05-06 14:39:59Z riggs $

[client]
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysql]
prompt                          = \u@\h [\d]>\_
no_auto_rehash

[mysqld]
user                            = mysql
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /tmp/mysql.sock
bind-address                    = 127.0.0.1
basedir                         = /usr/local
datadir                         = /var/db/mysql
tmpdir                          = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
slave-load-tmpdir               = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
secure-file-priv                = /var/db/mysql_secure
log-bin                         = mysql-bin
log-output                      = TABLE
master-info-repository          = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository       = TABLE
relay-log-recovery              = 1
slow-query-log                  = 1
server-id                       = 1
sync_binlog                     = 1
sync_relay_log                  = 1
binlog_cache_size               = 16M
expire_logs_days                = 30
default_password_lifetime       = 0
enforce-gtid-consistency        = 1
gtid-mode                       = ON
safe-user-create                = 1
lower_case_table_names          = 1
explicit-defaults-for-timestamp = 1
myisam-recover-options          = BACKUP,FORCE
open_files_limit                = 32768
table_open_cache                = 16384
table_definition_cache          = 8192
net_retry_count                 = 16384
key_buffer_size                 = 256M
max_allowed_packet              = 64M
query_cache_type                = 0
query_cache_size                = 0
long_query_time                 = 0.5
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 1G
innodb_data_home_dir            = /var/db/mysql
innodb_log_group_home_dir       = /var/db/mysql
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:128M:autoextend
innodb_temp_data_file_path      = ibtmp1:128M:autoextend
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size            = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_write_io_threads         = 8
innodb_read_io_threads          = 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 2
skip-symbolic-links

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
quote_names
quick
```

Такое впечатление, что mysql не види файлов БД в папке */var/db/mysql*
Кто в курсе подскажите пожалуйста решение. Спасибо.

Comment: *после обновления БД* После обновления обычной рабочей базы данных?

Comment: да, обновил все установленные пакеты на сервере и установил обновки на freebsd. После чего Mysql приказал долго жить.

Comment: *обновил все установленные пакеты на сервере и установил обновки на freebsd* Ну ни хрена себе у Вас понимание, что такое база данных... обновите уж тогда до кучи и сам MySQL - хуже-то всяко дело не станет.

Comment: Обновил mysql та же проблема

Comment: Я вообще думал, что люди ставящие release candidate версии способны к более глубокому анализу своего ПО чем "впечатление что не видит файлы"

Comment: Какая версия стояла ранее? Что у вас сейчас есть в datadir? Когда был последний бекап? К тому же 8.0.2 даже не RC, это ранняя dev версия.

Comment: /var/lib/mysql и внутри папки файлы и папки с названиями бд в которых есть только файлы с расширением *.ibd. Ранее стояла 8,0,1

Comment: Покажите `ls -lR /var/db/mysql` И почему вы сейчас написали про `/var/___lib___/mysql`? У вас там данные?

Comment: Скрины: http://iif.sspu.edu.ua/1.png и http://iif.sspu.edu.ua/2.png